# Is it correct to store field ids in DTO?

Tags: java, spring, rest, dto

Suppose I have the following class, in my Spring RESTful API:

```java
public class Order {
    private Integer id;
    private Store store;
    private Customer customer;
    private Product product;
}
```

When I receive a new Order to persist, is it correct to receive it as the following DTO and let the OrderService find by id each field, set to a new Order object and persist it?

```
public class NewOrderDTO {
    private Integer storeId;
    private Integer customerId;
    private Integer productId;
}
```

Can ModelMapper or any other framework do that?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What else should it receive? The client can't be trusted to have up-to-date information about the other fields of `Store`, `Customer`, and `Product`, so the code should only the the IDs anyway and lookup the object to verify the IDs are correct, and it would be a waste to transmit the full objects if you're not going to use them.

Comment: To get better answers, I would suggest changing the question, "is it correct to", to a more specific technical question

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the suggestion, it makes sense. But, in this case, is there a framework that helps to map the field ids of NewOrderDTO to the corresponding entities or should this be done in OrderService?

Comment: @NicolasHolanda That depends. If the `@Service` API is also the transaction boundary, i.e. the Service class or method is annotated with `@Transactional`, then it should receive the ID-only DTO, so it can do the lookups and order creation all in a single transaction. If not, then it's really the `@Controller` that specifies that it only need IDs, so it should do the lookups. I'd recommend the first option, i.e. having the Service do it, and having it be the transaction boundary.

Comment: @Andreas got it. I was already doing the first option, but not sure if it's correct. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: IMHO yes - it works well with most Web (eg Spring web) and persistence (eg JPA/Hibernate) frameworks

Comment: Since you are using Spring (and probably Jackson) you can use @JsonView to create projection of your dto so you dont have to mainain N classes, only 1 dto and its views.